# Ban icons from systray

Tags: system-tray

I have an application, which has a systray-icon. I want to make the icon disappear, without uninstalling the app. It should still keep on running in the background.

Thanks for your help.
kl

Comment: Whats the application?

Comment: alarm-clock-applet

Answer (score 1):

The program alarm-clock-applet can be built without indicator support, as indicated on the project page:

http://alarm-clock.pseudoberries.com/

instead of ./configure use ./configure --disable-indicator.

It solves my problem, but not the general question.
Thanks.